MySQL - trigger - limit update to one row
I simply want to restrain an update query on a specific table to one row or cancel it.
For multiple raisons I have to do that on the MySQL server side.
Here is my trigger:
DELIMITER //
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS prevent_multiple_update //
CREATE TRIGGER prevent_multiple_update
  BEFORE UPDATE ON `my_table`
  FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
       IF( @rows_being_updated IS NULL ) THEN
         SET @rows_being_updated = 1;
       ELSE
         SET @rows_being_updated = NULL;
         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
         SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot update more than one line per time';
       END IF;
  END //
DELIMITER ;

It works as expected for the first query, but only for the first one.
If I try:
UPDATE `my_table` SET company=1 WHERE id=1;

It works, the query is executed
If I try:
UPDATE `my_table` SET company=1 WHERE id=1 OR id=2;

It works, but the query is NOT executed
But, if I try:
UPDATE `my_table` SET company=1 WHERE id=1;
UPDATE `my_table` SET company=2 WHERE id=2;

The first one is executed but the second one trig the trigger and is not executed, it's like var @rows_being_updated is not set to null.
Any ideas?
Thank you.

What is your actual use case which requires limiting the number of rows to be updated?

The @rows_being_updated variable has a connection scope, hence its value is stored within the connection. You must reset this flag variable before insertion explicitly.

But it's supposed to be reset to NULL just before the SIGNAL command

CREATE TRIGGER prevent_multiple_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON test
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
       IF @update_timestamp = NOW(6) THEN
         SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
         SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Cannot update more than one line per time';
       ELSE 
         SET @update_timestamp = NOW(6);
       END IF;
END

fiddle
How does this works?
The function NOW(6) returns the datetime of the whole UPDATE query execution start (rather than SYSDATE()) with the microsecond accuracy. It is impossible that two consecutive queries starts within a microsecond. So when the query updates only one row then the value returned by this function differs from one which was set during previous UPDATE (or it is NULL if this is the most first UPDATE within the connection). When the query tries to update more than one row then the function returns the same value for each its call within the query, the trigger detects this on the 2nd row updation and breaks the query.

It work, you resolve my problem,
Thank You !

That's quite a smart way of using NOW(6) to generate a value which stays constant during its main statement. I wonder if it's possible to set the limit to a specific number instead of only 1 .

@blabla_bingo You'd add another user-defined variable that will count the number of rows with the current datetime, reset the value if the datetime values are different, and abort if the limit is reached. The limit can be both hardcoded and provided in the third user-defined variable which is set before or in the query.
